# pssh ignoring read command in script

Tags: ssh

I am running an installation on multiple servers using pssh.  During the installation I expect the script to prompt user for a password but this doesn't happen.

When I run the script on a single server it is successful but, when I use pssh via the following command, it fails.

```
pssh -h hostfile.txt -t 100000000 -A -l jolaoosup -P -I <./scripts
```

The script being used is as shown below:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-7.0.tar.gz --no-check-certificate    

echo "Download complete"  
tar xzf setuptools-7.0.tar.gz
echo "File untarred"  
cd setuptools-7.0  
echo "Changed directory to setup Tool"  
python setup.py install  
echo "setup.py installed"  
cd /home/jolaoosup/  
echo "Changed into Home directory"  
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py  
echo "Pip download successful"  
**read -sp "Password: " passvar**   -> when it failed to prompt for password  
echo  
echo Thank you for your login details  
echo $passvar | dzdo -S  python get-pip.py  
echo "get-pip installed"  
echo $passvar | dzdo -S easy_install --upgrade numpy  
echo "numpy upgrade completed"  
echo $passvar | dzdo -S easy_install  --upgrade pyparsing  
echo "pyparsing upgrade completed"  
echo $passvar | dzdo -S  pip install numpy scipy matplotlib pandas statsmodels  
echo "All available packages installed"
```

Comment: It's *possibly* because `pssh` doesn't allocate a TTY - you could try passing `-t` (or `-t -t`) as an extra option to SSH using the `-x` option: `-x '-t -t'`. See the (somewhat related) [“Force psuedo-tty allocation” doesn't translate to pssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197482/force-psuedo-tty-allocation-doesnt-translate-to-pssh)

Comment: What's this? `**read -sp "Password: " passvar**   -> when it failed to prompt for password` ?

Comment: @abu_bua I think it's the OP's attempt to highlight the location of the failure

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your input. I changed it to                                              pssh -h hostfile.txt -t 100000000 -x '-t -t' -A -l <user> -P -I <./python_libraries.sh

Comment: @DMOJ so... did it help?

Comment: At the prompt ,I get                                                                            [user@server ~]$ read -sp 'Password: ' passvar
Password:    
it prints my password on the screen and doesn't proceed, can you help

Comment: @steeldriver At the prompt ,I get [user@server ~]$ read -sp 'Password: ' passvar Password: it prints my password on the screen and doesn't proceed, can you help –

Comment: @DMOJ sorry no - that's the limit of my knowledge